# Sinon Stub Different Value returned each time

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm fairly new to TypeScript/JavaScript but I have a working VScode extension which I'm quite happy with. My issue is with my Mocha tests. I have the following function

```
export async function getPackInfo (): Promise<IPackInfo> {
  let validChars = '^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$'
  let ref
  ref = await getInput('Pack Reference (lowercase and (-) only)', 'pack-reference', 'my-first-pack')
  if (!ref.match(validChars)) {
    vscode.window.showErrorMessage('Pack name can only contain letters, numbers and dashes', 'Got it')
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Pack name can only contain letters, numbers and dashes. Pack will not be created correctly.'))
  }
  console.log(ref)
  let packname = ref.replace(/-/g, ' ').toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
  .join(' ')
  console.log(packname)
  let author
  if (getSetting('defaultAuthor')) {
    console.log('Got setting')
    author = getSetting('defaultAuthor')
  } else {
    console.log('Need input')
    author = await getInput('Pack Author', 'Pack Author', 'John Doe')
  }
  console.log(author)

  let email
  if (getSetting('defaultEmail')) {
    email = getSetting('defaultEmail')
  } else {
    email = await getInput('Author Email', 'Author Email', 'john@example.com')
  }
  console.log(email)
  if (!author || !email) {
    throw new Error('Pack author or email not defined')
  }
  // Write Pack Config File
  let data: IPackInfo = {
    'ref': ref,
    'packname': packname,
    'author': author,
    'email': email
  }
  return data
}
```

This function call another one called getInput which calls vscode.window.showInputBox:

```
export async function getInput (prompt: string, placeholder: string, defaultValue: string): Promise<string> {
  let value = await vscode.window.showInputBox({ prompt: prompt, placeHolder: placeholder, value: defaultValue }).then(function(value) {
    if (value) {
      resolve(value)
    }
    throw new Error('No value for prompt')
  })
```

I am trying to test that the data returns correctly in the 'getPackInfo' function. My test currently looks like this:

```
    it('Check that packname is converted correctly', function (done) {
      let mockGetInput
      mockGetInput = sinon.stub(vscode.window, 'showInputBox')
      mockGetInput.onFirstCall().resolves('ref-pack-here')
      mockGetInput.onSecondCall().resolves('Test Author')
      mockGetInput.onThirdCall().resolves('example@example.com')
      getPackInfo().then((res) => {
        let output = res['ref']
        console.log(`Output: ${res['packname']}`)
        console.log(`Output: ${res['author']}`)
        console.log(`Output: ${res['email']}`)
        console.log(`Output: ${res['ref']}`)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      done()
      mockGetInput.restore()
    })
```

I have been at this now for days but I cannot get each call to be a different value!

The first call returns correctly but all subsequent call do not return anything.

If there is a better way to do it I am more than happy to try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a few fixes to your `async` code.

---

Right now `getInput` *always* resolves to `undefined`.  `resolve` is undefined inside the `then` clause so that `Promise` always rejects with an error, but even if that issue didn't exist the `value` that *would* have otherwise been returned from `vscode.window.showInputBox` is never returned.

You can fix those issues by changing it to this:

```
export async function getInput (prompt: string, placeholder: string, defaultValue: string): Promise<string> {
  const value = await vscode.window.showInputBox({ prompt: prompt, placeHolder: placeholder, value: defaultValue });
  if (value) {
    return value;
  }
  throw new Error('No value for prompt')
}
```

---

You're creating the mock correctly, you just need to wait for the `Promise` returned by `getPackInfo` to resolve before restoring the mock and ending the test.

Right now it is calling `getPackInfo` and then immediately calling `done`, restoring the mock, and ending the test before any of the `async` code in `getPackInfo` has even had a chance to run.

The easiest way to fix that is to use an `async` test function and call `await` on the `Promise`:

```
it('Check that packname is converted correctly', async () => {  // async test function
  let mockGetInput;
  mockGetInput = sinon.stub(vscode.window, 'showInputBox');
  mockGetInput.onFirstCall().resolves('ref-pack-here');
  mockGetInput.onSecondCall().resolves('Test Author');
  mockGetInput.onThirdCall().resolves('example@example.com');
  const res = await getPackInfo();  // await the Promise
  console.log(`Output: ${res['packname']}`);
  console.log(`Output: ${res['author']}`);
  console.log(`Output: ${res['email']}`);
  console.log(`Output: ${res['ref']}`);
  mockGetInput.restore();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try that out and report back

Comment: I cannot thank you enough @brian-lives-outdoors.That has fixed my issue!